# If $x$ is an integer such that $\operatorname{gcf}(x, 24) = 8$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(x, 24) = 312$, find $x$.

Tags: functions

I'm confused with this problem. Any kind of help is appreciated. What are $\operatorname{gcf}(x,24)$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(x,24)$? Are they just another way to say $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)?$ What is the relation between $\operatorname{gcf}$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$?

> If $x$ is an integer such that $\operatorname{gcf}(x, 24) = 8$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(x, 24) = 312$, find $x$.

Comment: These functions are most likely the greatest common factor and least common multiple functions.

Comment: The greatest common factor of $x$ and $y$ times the lcm of $x$ and $y$, is equal to $xy$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCF means greatest common factor, but usually you will meet it as GCD, menaing greatest common divisor. On the other hand LCM means least common multiplier.

Anyway to solve the problem, one can use a well-know identity $LCM(a,b) \cdot GCD(a,b) = a\cdot b$. So just substitute $a=24$ and the given values to get the answer.

Comment: Note: to prove the identity given in this answer, consider the prime decompositions of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$gcf(x,24)=gcf(x,2^33^1)=2^3=8$$

Hence we conclude that $2^3$ divides $x$, and $3$ does not divide $x$.

Now use the clues from $lcm(x,24)=312$ to narrow down $x$ further.